# Grails Many-to-Many relationship not working as expected

Tags: grails, many-to-many, dynamic-forms

I'm a Grails newb and facing a difficult Many-to-Many relationship issue.

Here's the domain classes simplified:

```
class Comment {
    String title
    String comment

    static hasMany = [commentGroups:CommentGroup]

    static constraints = {
        title blank:true
        comment blank:false, maxSize:800
    }

    static mapping = {
        commentGroups cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }

}

class CommentGroup {

    String groupTitle

    static hasMany = [comments:Comment]
    static belongsTo = Comment

    static constraints = {
        groupTitle blank:true, nullable:true
    }
}
```

Here's a html extract from the form which is dynamically built using JS, PLEASE NOTE THAT ALL CODE I HAVE INCLUDED IS NOT COMPLETE IT'S JUST TO GIVE YOU AN IDEA OF WHAT I NEED TO ACHIEVE:

```html
<form class="m-b-d" role="form" name="comments" id="comments" method="post" action="/rootstofood/comment/save">



  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
    <label for="rating" class="control-label">Give us a star rating?</label>
    <div class="br-wrapper br-theme-bootstrap-stars">
      <select aria-describedby="Rating" name="rating" id="rating" class="form-control input-lg" style="display: none;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <div class="br-widget"><a href="#" data-rating-value="1" data-rating-text="1"><span></span></a><a href="#" data-rating-value="2" data-rating-text="2"><span></span></a><a href="#" data-rating-value="3" data-rating-text="3"><span></span></a><a href="#" data-rating-value="4"
        data-rating-text="4"><span></span></a><a href="#" data-rating-value="5" data-rating-text="5"><span></span></a>
        <div class="br-current-rating"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
    <label for="commentTitle" class="control-label sr-only">Any short comment header?</label>
    <input aria-describedby="Comment title" placeholder="Any short comment header?" value="" id="commentTitle" name="commentTitle" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="200">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
    <span class="sr-only" id="commentTitle">(success)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
    <label for="startComment" class="control-label sr-only">Start comment</label>
    <textarea rows="3" aria-describedby="Start comment" placeholder="Enter start comment" id="startComment" name="startComment" class="form-control input-lg vrequired" maxlength="400"></textarea>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
    <span class="sr-only" id="startComment">(success)</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Children or staff comments area START -->

  <!-- ##### Dynamic area START #### -->
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="comment-groups">

    <div class="panel panel-default p-trbl" data-group-id="0" id="comment-group-0" data-remove-group-id="0">
      <div class="ovh">
        <div class="pull-left"><b>Comment Group: 0</b>
        </div><a class="danger pull-right remove-comment-group" data-remove-group-id="0" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> Remove</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
          <label for="title" class="control-label sr-only">Any short comment header?</label>
          <input aria-describedby="Comment Group title" placeholder="Any short comment group header?" value="" name="commentGroups[0].groupTitle" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="200">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
          <span class="sr-only" id="title">(success)</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Children or staff comments area START -->
        <div class="col-sm-12" data-comments-group-id="0" id="comments">

          <div class="panel panel-default p-trbl" data-comment-group-id="GROUP" id="comment-0_0">
            <div class="ovh">
              <div class="pull-left"><b>Staff/Pupil Group/Comment: 0</b>
              </div><a class="danger pull-right remove-comment" data-remove-comment-id="0_0" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> Remove</a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
                <label for="startComment" class="control-label sr-only">Comment</label>
                <textarea id="commentGroups[0].comments[0].startComment" rows="3" aria-describedby="Comment" placeholder="Enter comment" name="commentGroups[0].comments[0].startComment" class="form-control input-lg vrequired" maxlength="400"></textarea>
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
                <span class="sr-only" id="comment">(success)</span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-10">
                <label for="name" class="control-label sr-only">Name</label>
                <input type="text" aria-describedby="Name" placeholder="Name" name="commentGroups[0].comments[0].name" class="form-control input-lg vrequired" maxlength="30">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
                <span class="sr-only" id="name">(success)</span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-2">
                <label for="type" class="control-label sr-only">Comment from</label>
                <select aria-describedby="Type" name="commentGroups[0].comments[0].type" id="type" class="form-control input-lg">
                  <option value="Parent">Parent</option>
                  <option value="Pupil">Pupil</option>
                  <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
                  <option value="KS1">KS1</option>
                  <option value="KS2">KS2</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
          <a data-comment-group-id="0" class="add-comment success" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add another pupil or staff comment</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Children or staff comments area END -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
    <a class="add-group success" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add another comment group</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Children or staff comments area END -->

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
    <label for="endComment" class="control-label sr-only">End comment</label>
    <textarea rows="3" aria-describedby="End comment" placeholder="Enter end comment" id="endComment" name="endComment" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="400"></textarea>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
    <span class="sr-only" id="endComment">(success)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-2">
    <label for="title" class="control-label sr-only">Title</label>
    <select aria-describedby="Title" name="title" id="title" class="form-control input-lg">
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
      <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
      <option value="Mr &amp; Mrs">Mr &amp; Mrs</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-10">
    <label for="firstName" class="control-label sr-only">Name</label>
    <input type="text" aria-describedby="Name" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" class="form-control input-lg vrequired" maxlength="60">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
    <span class="sr-only" id="Name">(success)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
    <label for="jobTitle" class="control-label sr-only">Job title</label>
    <input type="text" aria-describedby="Job title" placeholder="Job title" id="jobTitle" name="jobTitle" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="60">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
    <span class="sr-only" id="jobTitle">(success)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-12">
    <label for="organisation" class="control-label sr-only">Organisation</label>
    <input type="text" aria-describedby="Organisation" placeholder="Organisation" id="organisation" name="organisation" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="60">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback hidden"></span>
    <span class="sr-only" id="organisation">(success)</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback col-sm-2">
    <label for="type" class="control-label sr-only">Type</label>
    <select aria-describedby="Type" name="type" id="type" class="form-control input-lg">
      <option value="Parent">Parent</option>
      <option value="Pupil">Pupil</option>
      <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
      <option value="KS1">KS1</option>
      <option value="KS2">KS2</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>



  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg onWht" id="feedback" type="submit"><b>Submit Feedback <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></b>
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here's my incomplete controller save action which is pretty much out-of-the-box:

```
    def save() {
        def commentInstance = new Comment(params)

        if (!commentInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "index", model: [commentInstance: commentInstance])
            return
        }
        render(view: "thankyou")
}
```

So from the code I have a parent domain 'Comment' that has many 'GroupComment' which has many 'Comment'.

When I build my project my database gives me the following tables:

```
comment
comment_comment_groups
comment_group
```

Which surprised me as I had stipulated a Many-to-Many relationship so was expecting:

```
comment
comment_comment_groups
comment_group_comments
comment_group
```

I'm probably expecting Grails to do too much work here. So when I submit my comments form the database is populated with my parent 'Comment' and even the 'CommentGroup' domains belonging to the 'Comment' but the 'CommentGroup' comments do not get saved to the database.

I realise that I am being naive here, but what am I missing? Can anyone help as I have searched high and low and can not find a similar scenario. I know there are lots of Many-to-Many relationship examples but none that cover off my scenario.

In the meantime I will continue searching.

My guess is that I need to build a more complex 'save' action in my controller by manually handling the params, but would be good if there is a GORM way of achieving this.

Look forward to some answer... please be gentle on me :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove from Comment domain class commentGroups cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
and add in CommentGroup mapping: comments cascade: "all-delete-orphan".

new Comment(params).save() save comment group with all comments belongs to this group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer swiatows but I now get the below error message:

Comment: ...
Error |
2015-10-12 09:50:31,444 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - AssertionFailure occurred when processing request: [POST] /rootstofood/comment/save - parameters:
...
null id in rootstofood.Comment entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Stacktrace follows:
Message: null id in rootstofood.Comment entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)...

Comment: I think the null id in Comment is a clue but still don't know how to resolved this?

Comment: so the current transaction gets invalidated but then you are trying to proceed with more operations in that session. Check and validate params before you save comment.